# Beanshell general error when encountering class

Tags: java, beanshell

I took a look at some questions and did not find what I really need as an answer. I'm stuck on a script I want Micro-Manager (the microscopy software, check micro-manager.org for détails) to run.

When I run my script on beanshell I do the following imports:

```
import org.micromanager.navigation.PositionList;
import org.micromanager.PositionListDlg;
import org.micromanager.navigation.MultiStagePosition;
import org.micromanager.navigation.StagePosition;
import java.lang.System;
```

Then I call a new variable:

```
PositionList pl = gui.getPositionList();
```

and later a method

```
MultiStagePosition.goToPosition(pl.getPosition(l), mmc);
```

In a for loop where l is the counter.
I get an error log saying

"general error : PositionList "

but when I remove the declaration (just writing pl=gui.getPositionList();) I get a second log:

"general error:MultiStagePosition.goToPosition(pl.getPosition(l), mmc);"

I'm a real noob with Java and Beanshell so I'm more or less stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: Chek for null PositionList at gui.getPositionList() maybe you are getting a NPE.

Comment: Actually it was more simple. PositionList and MultiStagePosition have been moved from navigation to api in a recent update. Thank you anyway!